# Colloquial expression for "compliment" that carries negative feeling

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, colloquialisms

What is the colloquial/casual/conversational form of the word "compliment" in this context:

> A: I hate John.
>
> B: Why? He's like a genius.
>
> A: Exactly! He's such a teacher's pet. He's always gotta answer all the questions and Ms. Johnson is always complimenting him.

Here in Japan the phrase "Ms. Johnson is always complimenting him" carries a negative nuance. And this dialogue does not sound natural to me at all. School kids do not use the word *compliment* in this context as Japanese kids do.

Comment: Not really colloquial, but a more common word for what a teacher says to a student is "praise". *...and Ms. Johnson is always praising him.*

Comment: I thought of the word praise except a student never says to another student, " I hate Jimmy cause ms. Johnaon's always praising him. One reason being, "praise " has religious conotations.

Comment: A student never says that to another student?  Are you sure?  Are you sure?  Are you sure?  Are you... sorry, too much IT Crowd ;-)  Seriously, *are* you sure?  Your reason doesn't, IMHO, hold much water, since this connotation isn't that strong in this day and age: in other words: not many non-church-goers would think of religion when they hear "praise" *in the context we're talking of*

Comment: I think we might refer to it as a "backhanded compliment" or even "damning with faint praise".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch +1 for backhanded compliment; personally I don't think 'damning with faint praise' fits here though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a word replacement for compliment that carries a negative connotation, but I can restructure your dialog slightly:

> A: I hate John. B: why? He's like a genius. A: exactly! He's such a teachers pet. He's always kissing up to Ms. Johnson and she totally rewards him for it.

I am not sure that receiving compliments is considered negative in the US, the negativity comes from asking for compliments (often referred to as "fishing") or accepting them without humility.

Comment: Thanks, this is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Or maybe, "and ms. Johnson's always bragging about him to the class. Maybe??

Comment: yes, bragging about him publicly would be a source of problems. Even "Always gives him too many compliments" would work.

Answer (score 6):

What about, *give him props*?  As in,

"I had to give him props for finishing a 50-page paper in a single late-nighter."

One often hears "props" used colloquially as a replacement for the word "compliment" in urban slang.

Comment: and suburban slang too :) I would vote this as authentic teen-speak

Comment: Yes, if I was asking for an expression with a positive nuance I would have totally chosen this one. Thanks Billare.

Answer (score 3):

In this sense, something along the lines of *Brownie points* would seem to fit the bill. It has that combination of childishness, contempt (from peers) and favoritism (from the teacher) that you'd expect from 'tweens and teens.

Comment: Yeah, this is clearly the best answer (so far).  It even hearkens to the student-teacher relationship; the thought of brownies and grade school are strongly intertwined in my mind. Mmm. Brownies.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "to pay somebody a compliment" (we also say "to receive/accept/acknowledge a compliment") . Also, when someone "pays a compliment" to us, we might consider "repaying/returning" the compliment. Well, these are the colloquial phrases that come into my mind regarding "compliment". Hope this helps.

Comment: But would a student actually say to another student, " I hate John because the teacher is always paying him compliments"? That just doesn't sound normal.

Answer (score 1):

An informal word for *compliment* is *kudos*. I have never heard it used as verb (as in [*?*] *he was kudosing her*), but you can say *to receive kudos*, *to get kudos*, *to give kudos*, or similar phrases.

Comment: Ok would a student say," I hate John cause the teacher is always giving him kudos "?

Comment: No, you probably wouldn't hear a student say this. My 15 year old daughter would occasionally use "kudos," but not in this manner.

Answer (score -1):

The word I would choose to replace "complimenting" is "flattering":

> Exactly! He's such a teachers pet. He's always gotta answer all the questions and Ms. Johnson is always flattering him.

"Flattering" carries extremely negative connotations and is almost *never* a good thing to give or receive. (Exceptions arise when flirting.)